# Login flow using react-native-navigtion(v1) of wix

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

i want to have clarity on login flow of react native apps.

i am using react-native-navigation (v1,wix) ,

Login flow :

1. startsinglescreenapp with login component
2. on login success Again startsinglescreenapp with rootComponent
3. on clicking logout in rootComponent call App() , which will go to step one

Is above login is right ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct. 
Login single screen, then once login start another single screen based component or tab based component, once lout kick the user to the single login screen